# Uploading xml file and processing using flask

Tags: python, html, xml, flask, file-upload

I am developing a Python backend to which I send an xml file from the front end. This is so that I can generate python code based on it and show the contents in the front end. How can I do this using flask?
I have attached the code I tried below. It does not work for me. I was not able to save the xml file into a directory.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
from main import run
import os

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/submit/', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = xmltodict.parse(request.get_data())
        file = os.path.join(app.config['upload'].uploaded_file.filename)
        uploaded_file.save(file)
    return "Successfully uploaded"
@app.route('/submit/')
def convert():
    path='upload'
    os.chdir(path)
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
            run(file_path,'tmp','python')
    return  "Code generated"

@app.route('/view/')
def view_python_script():
    # Folder path
    path='tmp'
    os.chdir(path)
    content=""
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                content = content + f.read().replace('\n','<br>')
    return render_template('upload.html', details=content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I occupy this: `uploaded_file = request.files ['file_upload']`.

`file_upload` I pass it from the html with the parameter `name = "file_upload"` of `input` contained within the `form`.
The problem I have is that when I want to share it in another html page it closes and throws me a `ValueError: I / O operation on closed file`.
But well, I hope it helps you !!!